# IntelliJ IDEA set default debug view to console view

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Is there a settings configuration to set the default view, once in Debug mode, to the console box, and thus view the printed output? Every time I re-enter debug mode I have to click on the Console tan. I spent the last half hour digging through the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "Console" tab. In the context menu that opens, choose "Focus On Startup".